# Showing a transformation maps a comple number to a series of concentric circles

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I'm trying to show that the function $f(Z)=\frac{1}{z-z_1}$ maps a family of circles $C_k$ into a series of concentric circles. Do the circles $C_k$ need to be centered at the origin? If so, how do I prove it? Where do I go from there? Do I need to show that $f(Z)$ is a conformal map?

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=\frac1{z-z_1}$ and assume $|z-z_1|= k^2$ represents a family of circles $C_k$ with the center $z_1$ and the radius $k$. Then,

$$|w|^2 = \frac1{|z-z_1|^2}=\frac1{k^2}$$

which shows a series of concentric circle with the center at origin and the radius $\frac1k$.